# Can one set an environment variable in an intellij run configuration with a macro?

Tags: intellij-idea

Specifically I want to set an environment variable to be present in the runtime process for a java application and use the value of $OutputPath$ as part of it's definition.

Can this be done ?
If so how ?

Thanks.

Comment: There is a related feature-request in IntelliJ IDEA issues tracker https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-305799